# I want to buy a building's corner?

Tags: possessives

If I am an insane person wanting to buy a corner of some building, can I say:

> I want to buy a building's corner?

Or it should necessarily be said like:

> I want to buy a corner of some building?

I mean can we create the possession forms ('s) for non-alive objects?

If it's alive ones, we can:

> I want to by my father's car

etc.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=building+corner%2Cbuilding%27s+corner%2C+%28corner+of+the+building+%2B+corner+of+a+building%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3 suggests *corner of a/the building* occurs around 100 times more frequently than your suggestion. There is no rule, but yes, in general you can append *'(s)* to non-living things. Sometimes using a noun to modify another noun is more common (*car keys*), and other times the *of* thing is the most natural.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use possessives (which aren't always about possession *per se*) where the 'possessor' is inanimate.

> My car's windscreen needs replacing.

Indeed, the possessive pronoun *its* is basically used with animals, abstract entities, and inanimate objects as antecedents.

In the specific case you mention, it would not be natural. There's no reason. Sometimes the genitive *'s* is more natural, and sometimes an *of* construction is more natural. You just have to learn it from experience.

Comment: So, the choice of "the building's corner" and "a corner of the building" isn't about formal or informal, they are the same?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko: They are the same, and you would say *the building's corner* or *the corner of the building* interchangeably, but you wouldn't normally say "a building's corner", it's just not natural.

Comment: The main thing if it's not incorrect:)

Comment: What do you mean by 'correct'?

Comment: It's like it can exist in grammar. "He work" can't, it's incorrect. "He's working" - informal but correct. And our "the building's corner" is though not very natural but correct gramatically

Correct grammatically or grammatically correct...?

Comment: Well, English grammar has a lot of grey areas, but I wouldn't consider it grammatically incorrect, no.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your sentence is possible. (It's certainly grammatical.)

However, the common interpretation of the first sentence is not what you think it is (and it's not because of the possessive).

> I want to buy a building's corner.

I've never heard of people buying *just* the corner of a building before. So, if I heard this I would interpret it differently:

> I want to buy the *corner of the block on which a building stands*.

In this interpretation, *the building's* ***corner*** is referring to something else—although still something that's associated with it.

---

To make it explicitly clear that it's the physical component of the building, you could say:

> I don't want to buy the *entire* building. I just want to buy one of its corners.

Or, possibly:

> I want to buy the building's southwest corner and all of the offices therein.

Again, the possessive is fine—it's the subject being referenced that needs clarification.

---

But if you use a different *particular* sentence, this type of confusion won't exist—and the regular possessive can easily be used:

> The building's windows were broken.
>   I want to paint the building's hallway walls.
>   The storm flooded the building's lobby.

Comment: It's okay, it's buying just the corner because if I am the insane person :D
I wanted to ask about grammar having made out some weird example:)